# Windows 7 installation: No hard drives found (Dell Vostro)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers

My Dell Vostro 3500 (anno 2010) laptop lost it's hard drive which I easily replaced. Problem: The laptop was not shipped with a Windows installation media, so the recovery options was located on the faulty hard drive.

Dell Denmark asks almost $100 to send a new installation media. Luckily I found a clean Windows 7 OEM iso file online, which *should* be working with my license key.

I don't get that far.

The Windows installation says **No drives were found. Click load driver to provide a mass storage driver for installation**.

I already tried:

- Changing hard drive setting to and from AHCI to Legacy IDE in BIOS.
- Providing the installation with the Intel Rapid Storage driver provided by Dell as well as the chipset drivers. No other drivers seem relevant to the hard drive.

Nothing seems to help. Any advice?

Comment: Do all your hard drives appear in your BIOS? Have you tried AHCI mode while providing the drivers from Intel during the Windows installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly Windows Setup does not list hard drives partitioned in a away it does not understand. I think my hard drive had been formatted for a Unix system.

Solution is really simple. From the Windows Setup access the repair utilities and use command prompt to access diskpart as follows:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

Now use that info to select your disk

```
select disk=1
```

And the next command will clear the disk, so if you are not going to use all of the hard drive please be aware not to lose any data now!

```
clean
```

Voila. Hit the close button and start the setup process again, the disk will be there.

I had a bonus problem, Windows could not find or create a system partition...

Solution to that problem was install in IDE-mode and/or set hard drive to 1st boot priority. This seems to be a USB-install bug.

Answer (score 0):

Dell laptops from this era seem yo ship with three options in their BIOS:

- Regular AHCI mode.
- Ancient backward compatability mode
- Fake RAID mode.

By default Dell sets these to RAID.

Windows 7 ships with a lot of drivers and it will install just fine if you set the disk to AHCI mode. If you set it to RAID mode then you will need to load drivers. Without these drivers winows will not see any of the harddisks and you have no place to install to.

That mean you have to solutions:

1. Set the disk to normal AHCI mode. It will work perfectly.
2. Set disk access to RAID mode and load the correct drives on a pen drive. During setup load the drivers when asked to do so (F^).

Comment: Might be worthy to note that you can use the Windows 7 USB Download tool from Microsoft to create a thumbdrive containing the windows 7 installation files based on that ISO you managed to obtain. You can then add a folder in the same thumbdrive with the drivers.

Comment: True. There are many ways to do this. MS tools for MBR disks. Or manually (format NTFS, copy files from the iso, run bootsect /nt60). Or format the pendrive as FAT32 and move the EFI boot files around. Lots of ways to make a bootable pen drive and also add the drivers.